# SymPy gives wrong eigenvalues?

Tags: python, anaconda, sympy, spyder

I am using SymPy in Anaconda/Spyder and eigenvals function gives wrong eigenvalues for a particular 4x4 matrix.

The code is:

```py
from sympy import *

x = sqrt((sqrt(5)-1)/2)
a = Matrix([[x**2, -x, -x, 1]])
b = Matrix([[-x, -x**2, 1, x]])
c = Matrix([[-x, 1, -x**2, x]])
d = Matrix([[1, x, x, x**2]])

e = zeros(1, 4)
e = e.row_insert(0,a)
e = e.row_insert(1,b)
e = e.row_insert(2,c)
e = e.row_insert(3,d)
e.row_del(4)
e *= x**2

e.eigenvals()
```

and it gives
+/- sqrt(1 +/- 2 * sqrt(9 - 4 * sqrt(5)))

(sorry, I am not allowed to post images)

but also doing

```py
lam=symbols('lambda') 
cp= det(e- lam*eye(4))
roots(Poly(cp,lam))
```

gives the correct answer, 1 and -1, both with multiplicity 2.

Comment: I tried with SymPy version 1.4 and I get `e.eigenvals(): {-1: 2, 1: 2}` as expected.